# Errors in pupbook.cls

Tags: errors

I have just downloaded `pupbook.zip` file from web (https://press.princeton.edu/authors), some errors are there when running the sample file and the errors are listed below:

```
Runaway argument?
\x@protect \[\protect \[  \@nil  \@ifpackageloaded {amstex}{\def \@tempa \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.9669 \newenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par

? 

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}
```

.

Please suggest what went wrong in this...

Comment: @egreg Sorry, please check this link https://press.princeton.edu/math/TeX/Macro_Guide.html

Comment: The README.txt file has an email address for contacting PUP about problems with the class.

Comment: @egreg If possible can you help me where the exact error was, actually it shows two errors, I fixed one and the next one not able to find out, anyhow, thanks for the attention on my request....

Comment: i can't offer any help, but notice that it is checking for `amstex`.  that's ancient (pre-1995) -- i wonder why it's still there?

Comment: You need to comment the code for `\textsubscript` (lines 8535 to 8538); also lines 8523 to 8527 (for `\medspace`, `\:` and `\!`). Then start your document with `\RequirePackage{amsmath}`. The class is a nightmare (a bad copy of `memoir`).

Comment: @egreg Yes, its working now, thanks a lot...

Comment: I get another errors when running the `pupbook`: `line 8320: ! LaTeX Error: Command \counterwithin already defined.
Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.` When I change `thmnumcontwithchapter` option to `thmnumcontinue` I get an elementary error also.

Comment: @C.F.G Did you solve the error? If not so, can you send the link where you got the template?

Comment: No. But it seems that changing `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand` resolves the error. https://press.princeton.edu/math/TeX/Macro_Guide.html

Comment: @C.F.G Glad to hear that you fixed the error...